# C File reading doesn't stop

Tags: c

I am writing a simple server that allows sending files using HTTP protocol. I have a function that puts everything from the file into buffer. 
Everything goes well before **read**. The file size is printed correctly. But on **read** program just waits.

```
char *get_file(char *dir) {
    fprintf(stderr, "GET FILE\n");
    char *buff;
    int fd;
    if (fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No such file: %s\n", dir);
        exit(6);
    }

    size_t size = fsize(dir);

    fprintf(stderr, "OPENED FILE, SIZE: %ld\n", size);
    buff = malloc(size);
    read(fd, buff, size);

    fprintf(stderr, "to be downloaded: %s\n", buff);
    char *response = make_file_response(buff);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: This `fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY) == -1` is wrong, print `fd` after that line and check. Enable compiler warnings too. Use `%zu` for `size_t` in `printf()`.

Comment: important : download a C/C++ IDE with a correct debugger, and use it

Comment: Please @user1952009 note that `c/c++` is, undefined behaviour. And in fact, there is no such language. So suggest a C and/or C++ IDE. Since this is all  [tag:c] code, then a C IDE. I know it looks like *it doesn't really matter* but, inexperienced programmers develop the feeling that [tag:c] and [tag:c++] are the same languages not-{,object oriented} respectively. It also does not require a debugger, that's is almost useless if the OP doesn't know that `fd == 0` wouldn't make sense in this scenario. Compilation Warnings on the other hand are crucial here.

Comment: @iharob : I don't agree with you, at all (except for the compilation warnings of course)

Comment: @iharob : did you already work on a huge source code that you didn't write ? because it seems you are thinking that understanding a code by reading it is the most important, whereas when you work on someone else code, with many function/methods calls that (at first) you  understand nothing of, you understand the code while debugging it, not by reading it. and here the situation is exactly the same with fd = open(...); I don't know how it works and what arguments it is expecting.

Comment: @user1952009 That is not a requirement, I think it's just my opinion and it might make sense to others so I commented. But it's certainly just my opinion and it might very well be wrong. Although, the FACT that [tag:c] and [tag:c++] are NOT the same language is that, a FACT.

Comment: @user1952009 I think you did not understand what I meant at all. I didn't say that debuggers are useless. But the problem in this code does not require a debugger yet, to detect it compilation warnings are MORE THAN ENOUGH. Also, if I am unable to understand code by reading it, I think I would write it from scratch instead. Perhaps the company won't let me do this but I would certainly want to. And maybe, it would save time and effort to re-write it.

Comment: @iharob : did you already work on a huge source code / software that you didn't write ? the debugger is the most important tool in the life of a developper, much more important than the language

Comment: @user1952009 Again, the debugger is indeed the most important tool. I will not say the contrary. I am just saying that it's not necessary to find `fd = open(...) == -1`  is a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112841/discussion-between-iharob-and-user1952009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an issue with this statement

```
if (fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY) == -1)
```

according to operator precendence `==` is evaluated first and thus, `fd` is being assigned the value of the comparison and not the opened file descriptor.

With compiler warnings enabled parentheses would be suggested, and the correted expression would be

```
if ((fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY)) == -1) 
/*  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ */
```

would first assign the return value of `open()` to `fd` and then the comparison is performed.

If you print the value of `fd` you will see that it's `0` if `open()` succeeded *i.e. returned a value not `-1`* and `1` otherwise.